# native script , How to fix problems with navigation in mobile apps?

Tags: nativescript

I have an application in nativescript which when you are browsing, has delay. then its operation is correct but then it stops when you are navigating.

I do not know the reason for the delay of the application since it is simple navigation

this is the routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full",

    },
    {
       path: "login", loadChildren: "./login/login.module#LoginModule"
      //  path: "login", component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "mesas", loadChildren: "./mesas/mesas.module#MesasModule"

       //  path: "mesas", component: MesasComponent,

    },
    {
       //   path: "home",    loadChildren: "./home/home.module#HomeModule"
         path: "home", component: HomeComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "comanda", loadChildren: "./comanda/comanda.module#ComandaModule"
        //  path: "comanda", component: ComandaComponent,
    },
    {
        //   path: "subP-Mod",   loadChildren:  "./comanda/modificadores.module#ModificadoresModule"

        path: "subP-Mod", component: ModificadoresComponent,
    },
    {
         //  path: "nOrden", loadChildren: "./orden/nueva.module#NuevaModule"
        path: "nOrden", component: NOrdenComponent
    },
    {
        // path: "meseros",  loadChildren: "./meseros/meseros.module#MeserosModule"
        path: "meseros", component: MeserosComponent
    },
    {
        // path: "comensales", loadChildren:  "./comensales/comensales.module#ComensalesModule"
        path: "comensales", component: ComensalesComponent
    },
    {
        //path: "prodlibre",  loadChildren:  "./productoLibre/prodlibre.module#ProdLModule"
        path: "prodlibre", component: ProdLComponent
    },
    {
        // path: "razonDet",  loadChildren: "./razonesCancela/razonDetC.module#razonDetModule"
       path: "razonDet", component: RazonesComponent
    },



];
```

Comment: Are you using Webpack? Do you think it's platform specific, which OS you are testing it with? Your navigation could be slow if you render a lot of UI elements (100s) initially, you should try using ListView / render them post navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `"markingMode": "none"`, as described [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/marking-mode-none). There are a few drawbacks, but the navigation should feel much snappier